# React Native site shows the word Online even if the JSON file does not have a link

Tags: react-native

I have this mobile application page that shows services offered by my company and their address. If the services have a web address then it is supposed to show the word "Online" on the Mobile app, if not, then it is not supposed to show the word online. I am showing the services using flatlist. Below is part of my code to show the "online" word if the services exists or not exists.

```
 handleClick = (link) => {
    Linking.canOpenURL(link).then(supported => {
        if (supported) {
            Linking.openURL(link);
        } else {
            console.log('Don\'t know how to open URI: ' + link);
        }
    });
};


<View style={styles.AddressRow}>
                            {
                                    item.Online != ''? <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => Linking.openURL(  item.Online )}>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>: null 

                             }


                          <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => Linking.openURL(item.Online)}>
                                            <Text style={styles.underLineText}>Online</Text>
                         </TouchableOpacity>
```

My JSON file looks like below:

```
[


    {
        "id":"1",
        "fk": 1,
        "addr": "Test Drive",
        "phone": "951-955-6200",
        "LatL":"33.9",
        "Long2":"-117.373423",
        "Online": "http://www.test.com",

        "image" : "png"
     },



     {
        "id":"3",
        "fk": 1,
        "addr": "1234 Test drive",
        "phone": "951-955-6200",
        "LatL":"33.7",
        "Long2":"-116.971169",
        "Online": "",
        "image" : "Home"


     }
]
```

everything is displayed correctly except the online word shows up even if the Online is empty in the JSON file :     "Online": "",

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to do an inline if with a logical operator

```
<View style={styles.AddressRow}>
  {item.Online !== '' && <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => Linking.openURL(item.Online)}>
    <Text style={styles.underLineText}>Online</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator

Alternatively you could do an Inline If-Else with Conditional Operator

```
<View style={styles.AddressRow}>
  {item.Online !== '' ? (<TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => Linking.openURL(item.Online)}>
      <Text style={styles.underLineText}>Online</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>) : null}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator

Comment: Thank you. I used the first option.

Comment: That’s the one I usually use myself